# org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.NullPointerException exception in jboss AS 7.1.1

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss

I found an error org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.NullPointerException exception while deploying the war file.my code is as follows.

```
 public class ReminderService extends HttpServlet implements Runnable{

   public void init() throws ServletException {

      LogMsg.info("I am init()");
      ReminderService rThread = new ReminderService();
      refresher = new Thread(rThread);
      refresher.start();
      LogMsg.info("I am from appointments refresh Method.Thread is started now");

}

@Override
public void run() {

try {
        LogMsg.info("I am from run Method.");           
        obj.somefunction();             
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        LogMsg.info("I am from run Method.Thread woke up from sleep");

    }catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    run();
  }
}
```

Here i want to call the this servlet class init() by default i mean while deploying the war file but the problem is it is not triggered automatically,please let me know i am new to this.

Here the problem is in run method when i tried to call any other methods it is raising the error as mentioned as below.Please let me know the wrong thing.Thanks in advance.

```
    This is the message i got in console

ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-       host].[/ThanQDoctor].[org.jboss.tools.thanqdoctor.rest.JaxRsActivator]]     (http--127.0.0.1-8080-3) Servlet.service() for servlet org.jboss.tools.thanqdoctor.rest.JaxRsActivator threw exception: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleApplicationException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:340) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:214) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleInvokerException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:190) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:540) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:502) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:119) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```